# when i get the variable with Request is empty

Tags: mysql, laravel, request

this is the error i get : "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Le champ 'username' ne peut être vide (null) (SQL: update `user` set `username` = ?, `pseudo` = ?, `email` = ?, `password` = ? where `id` = 29)"

```
public function updateUser($id, Request $request)
{
    if ($id != NULL) {
        $username = $request->get('username');
        $pseudo = $request->get('pseudo');
        $email = $request->get('email');
        $password = $request->get('password');
        $retour = testToken();
        if($retour == TRUE) {
            $data = User::where('id', $id)->update(array('username'=>$username, 'pseudo'=>$pseudo, 'email'=>$email, 'password'=>$password));
            return response()->json([
                'message'=>'OK',
                'data'=>$data]
            ,200);
        } else {
            return response()->json([
                'message'=>'Forbidden',
            ]
            ,403);
        }
    } else {
        return response()->json([
        'message'=>'Not found',
        ]
        ,404);
    }       
}
```

[image]

dd($request->input());
i get an empty array :[image]

Comment: Might not make a difference, but try switching the order of variable injection: `updateUser(Request $request, $id)`. Confirm the values before saving (`dd($request->input());`), and make sure your form/ajax request/whatever is sending the proper data.

Comment: i try but that change nothing

Comment: Continue with the rest of the debugging process. `$username` is `null`, so somewhere in transition, the data is not being sent or received properly.

Comment: what is your content-type?

Answer (score 0):

Ok the answer was take param with this way :

`$username = Input::get('username');
$pseudo = Input::get('pseudo');
$email = Input::get('email');
$password = Input::get('password');`

Comment: You shouldn't have to do that. Check your content type in your postman request.